# Hotel charging 21% VAT in Argentina?

Tags: hotels, argentina, taxes, tax-refunds

I had the idea that foreign visitors are exempt from this tax when they pay with a foreign credit card, still my hotel manager insists I need to pay this tax. Since there is a language barrier between us, I'm looking for a reference in Spanish I can point him to (if I'm indeed correct).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¡Sí! Had to learn how to make google search Spanish (latin america) pages first.

Here's a news article about it: [Argentina devolverá IVA por hotel para atraer turistas extranjeros](http://www.pulso.cl/economia-dinero/argentina-devolvera-iva-por-hotel-para-atraer-turistas-extranjeros/)

And here's the official bulletin from the government: [Administración Federal de Ingresos Públicos
y Ministerio de Turismo
IMPUESTO AL VALOR AGREGADO](https://www.boletinoficial.gob.ar/#!DetalleNormaBusquedaRapida/156919/20161230/Turismo).

Hopefully those two articles should be enough to explain it to him in Spanish.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to be clear, this states that hotels shouldn't charged this tax to foreigners with foreign credit cards? Or is the full amount (with tax) charged automatically and the tax then refunded?

Comment: @user1073075 it should just be refunded (English version: http://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2016/09/29/argentina-hotel-vat-eliminated/) automatically if you pay with a foreign credit card.  Who implements this 'automatic refund' however, I'm not sure - banks, I'd guess?

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add that, when you pay, keep the receipts. And if none is provided, ask for them.

You can request your VAT charges back at the airport, after security and check-in.

That was my last experience. But it was years ago. It may have changed by now.

All the best!
Lucas